# Best Practice to load "content-wrapper" from "sidebar" or "navbar"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hello I need a way to fast load content in bootstrap, my application should have jqgrid, charts, jquery UI, and etc..

My problem is when i use function load my jquery functions doesnt load propely, eg: jqgrid

when parameter u=url of content with jqgrid with < scripts > < css > and etc.

```
function contentDisp(url)
{
  $(".content-wrapper").load('load.php?u='+url);
}
```

is there a better way to to this?? like an application with preload libraries.